# How to enable boot mode?

Tags: pins, linux, bootloader

I am currently working with the Allwinner T113-I EVB SoC, and I'm encountering an issue related to the BOOT-SEL0 and BOOT-SEL1 pins.

In the user manual for this SoC, it's mentioned that to boot from the SD card (SMHC0), the BOOT-SEL0 and BOOT-SEL1 pins should be set to '1' and '1', respectively. On the circuit diagram, these pins are identified as PC4 and PC5, which appear to be physically soldered to the eMMC, as indicated on the PCB schematic.

To check the status of the BOOT-SEL0 and BOOT-SEL1 pins, the manual suggests examining bits [11:12] of the address 0x03000024.

I attempted to read the value at address 0x03000024 in a Linux environment using the busybox devmem command. The command executed successfully, but the output was consistently "0x00000103."

I also tried writing to this address in an attempt to change its value, but it had no effect.

For reference, here is the PCB schematic: https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-I_EVB_V1_0_PCB.pdf

And here is the link to the user manual: https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_User_Manual_V1.5.pdf

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why the BOOT-SEL0 and BOOT-SEL1 pins appear to be stuck at "0x00000103" and how I can correctly configure them to boot from the SD card. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: image from documentation]

Comment: Presuming the these pins are connected to **inputs** of the eMMC, you'll need to add pull-up resistors and remove any pull-down resistors. This allows configuration at boot time without affecting normal operation (assuming fairly weak pull-ups/downs). Presumably, there are currently pull-down resistors to force the boot configuration to "00". You'll need to find these and remove them. Hopefully, there will be unpopulated pull-ups that you can populate  to change the boot bit to "11".